# How do I unpin and remove all IPFS content from my machine?

Tags: ipfs

I've added a bunch of files via `ipfs add`. How do I unpin and remove all of these at once?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

to unpin all added content:

`ipfs pin ls --type recursive | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 ipfs pin rm`

then optionally run storage garbage collection to actually remove things:

`ipfs repo gc`

Comment: `ipfs pin ls -q --type recursive -q | xargs ipfs pin rm` seems to work for me. `-n1` would make one instance of ipfs for each pin, pretty slow.

Comment: There is a mistake with the repeated -q flag here. Otherwise it works nicely.

Comment: `ipfs pin rm $(ipfs pin ls -q --type recursive)` also works

Comment: @protometa your method there runs the risk of creating a command too long for the shell to execute.

Comment: Seems like when I do: `du -sh .ipfs` its size still remain same

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 and protometa's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to jclay's answer, you might also want to delete everything on MFS:

```
ipfs files ls / | while read f; do ipfs files rm -r "/$f"; done
```

(Obligatory warning that this won't work if paths contain newlines.)

Comment: I needed to add a slash in the filename like:

```ipfs files ls / | while read f; do ipfs files rm -r "/$f"; done```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Daniel's answer, here's how to do it in a Docker container

`docker exec ipfs_container_name ipfs pin ls --type recursive | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 docker exec ipfs_container_name ipfs pin rm`

Replace `ipfs_container_name` with the name of your docker container.