# How can I completely clean IPFS repo?

Tags: garbage-collection, ipfs

After running following command, related: [How do I unpin and remove all IPFS content from my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43118023/2402577):

```sh
# unpin and remove all IPFS content from my machine
ipfs pin ls --type recursive | cut -d' ' -f1 | ifne xargs -n1 ipfs pin rm
ipfs repo gc
```

Size of the `.ipfs` repo still remains as it is:

```sh
$ du -sh ~/.ipfs
1.4G    .ipfs
```

---

I can do `rm -rf ~/.ipfs && ipfs init` but my IPFS id is re-initialized where I want to keep my original peer identity without removing it.

I want to completely clean content of the IPFS repo. How can I achieve it? I observe that after removing pinned objects still size of the `~/.ipfs` is not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing pinned objects do not change repo size. Blocks will be deleted during GC later if they are *not used* by anything else like **MFS**.

If you are using *flatfs* datastore, then storage space will be freed. In *badgerds* they will be overwritten by newer content but usually not freed.

Comment: How can I use `flatfs` datastore for ipfs? What should I force to free the ipfs repo size?

Comment: flatfs is in default profile https://docs.ipfs.io/how-to/default-profile/

Comment: I am using `"prefix": "flatfs.datastore",` as default but storage space is not freed, ipfs repo side remains as it is

Comment: blocks/ subsdirectory will shrink after GC. If not then blocks are referenced in MFS too. do ipfs files ls / to check what is inside MFS.

Comment: can't I just do `rm -f ~/.ipfs/badgerds`?

Comment: IPFS won't start if root MFS block is missing

Comment: Ah so my only option is to run `ipfs repo gc`

Comment: GC = Garbage Collection. Maybe assume everyone is a newbie when posting on StackOverflow. Using abbreviations doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The ipfs garbage collector isn’t enabled by default and caches can grow unrestrained unless garbage collection is run manually or enabled to run on a schedule.

Try running Garbage Collection via the command

```
ipfs repo gc
```

Note: pinned resources are never deleted by the garbage collector.

Read more over here: https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/persistence/#garbage-collection.

Comment: even I unpinned all the files and run : `ipfs rep gc` the rep does not completely cleaned